# Difference between "get dressed" and "dress", "get changed" and "change"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

There is a sentence:

> "It only takes five minutes to dress in the morning."

If I say instead,

> "It only takes five minutes to get dressed in the morning."

Is there any difference?

Similarly, if I say

> "I want to take a shower and get changed."  *-or-*
>   "I want to take a shower and change."

Is there any difference?

If there is any difference, even slightly, what is it?

Comment: I found this interesting note in [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dress), *dress* (v.) "to put on clothes. This verb is common in writing, but when you are speaking it is more usual to say that you get dressed".

Comment: Also, *marry* and *get married*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In normal, conversational speech (NY, USA), you wouldn't ever just 'dress'. Most likely you would 'get dressed' in the morning. Exceptions would include common phrases that use the passive tone, "dress(ed) for the occasion", or "dress(ed) for success" or "Dress(ed) up/down".

As for "change/get changed", they seem to be completely interchangeable, except that "get changed" seems to be slightly more *[intransitive](http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/various-grammar-rules/transitive-vs-intransitive-phrasal-verbs)*, meaning that it can stand alone, and usually sounds more awkward when it takes an object.

For example, I wouldn't say that I'd "**get changed** *into*" something; rather I'd "**change** *into something more comfortable...*"

Another example could be this exchange of two friends, one of whom who just finished working out at the gym...

> A. "I'm starving! Let's get a burger."
>
> B. "Ooh! That sounds wonderful! [looking down] Let me get (dressed/changed), and I'll meet you here in 5."

Comment: Interesting. Would you _dress yourself_ (say, if you're a parent saying it to a child, for instance)? Would it be unusual to hear it, or is it just uncommon? (That is, if someone said it, would you think it's was odd as in "wrong", or odd as in "rarely said"?)

Comment: @jimsug To me, it sounds odd as in "Yeah, sounds grammatical, but no native speaker would ever say that."

Comment: There's nothing strange about a parent asking a child (of appropriate age) to "dress yourself". There are probably more common ways, such as "put your clothes on yourself" and "get dressed [by] yourself" (i.e., alone as well as unaided)

Answer (score 6):

JasonS is right about the intransitive aspect of 'get changed/get dressed'.  But there is another dimension as well.  'Get changed/get dressed' has a *perfective* aspect (describing action towards a completed state) that change/dress does not always have.  This would be similar to the difference between an object 'getting bent' (i.e., entering a semi-permanent new shape) or 'bending' (changing shape, but possibly returning on its own to its original shape)

For this reason,

My daughter Jessica dresses herself = My daughter Jessica *knows how to* put on her clothes *with some degree of success (partial or complete)*

My daughter Jessica gets dressed by herself = My daughter Jessica *can put on an entire outfit* by herself

Comment: And a  somewhat related nuance:  "Dress" or "change" refers to the activity of changing attire.  After completing the activity, the person will be dressed or changed.  In "get dressed" or "get changed", "get" means "become", so these terms imply the activity but refer to the result.  In actual usage, people aren't likely to think about that distinction, though.  An exception would be a situation where two people are running late and one is talking to the other who spends forever on the process of getting dressed.  They would use "get dressed" to focus on the goal of achieving the result.

Answer (score 5):

In modern usage, there is absolutely no difference between *dress* and *get dressed* or *change* and *get changed*.

I would expect that in times past, *get dressed* or *get changed* would have implied that you had someone to assist you in those activities, while *dress* and *change* would have implied that you will be performing those activities without help; but that's strictly conjecture on my part.